# Getting a value from an inside an Optional with isPresent()

Tags: java, option-type

I have a `User` and associated time-limited `Role`s. I want to know if a `User` has a particular `UserRole` *and* it is unexpired. I can turn the user's roles into a stream, `filter()` it and `findFirst()`, giving me an `Optional`.

**Role**

```
public class Role {
    private UserRole role;
    private Date expiry;
    
    public boolean isUnexpired () {
        return (expiry == null) ? true : expiry.after(new Date());
    }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User {
  //...
  private Collection<Role> roles

  public boolean hasRole (UserRole userRole) {
    return roles.stream()
      .filter(r -> r.getRole().equals(userRole))
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(ur -> {  /* ... herein the problem ... */ ur.isUnexpired(); } );
  }
}
```

The problem in that last line is that `ifPresent()` has a void signature; as such, I can't return `ur.isUnexpired()` from it. Whatever I put in the lambda expression or anonymous inner class at that point can't do anything meaningfully with the value it finds.

I tried declaring a boolean before filtering the stream, and assigning it, but get the (code validation) error: `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`.

(I know, there's a bit more to handle when it's not present; if I can sort this, I can swap to `ifPresentOrElse()`.)

I could do the following:

```
  public boolean hasRole (UserRole userRole) {
    Optional<Role> o = roles.stream()
      .filter(r -> r.getRole().equals(userRole))
      .findFirst();
    return o.isPresent() ? o.get().isUnexpired() : false;
  }
```

However, I would rather do it with a cleaner, chained function.

Is there some way to extract and use my `isUnexpired()` boolean with a chained function? Or must I assign the `Optional` then operate on it separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care if a user has ANY unexpired entry of a `UserRole` in `Collection<Role> roles`, matching with a predicate using `anyMatch()` is a clearer and more concise approach:

```java
public boolean hasRole (UserRole userRole) {
   return roles.stream()
       .anyMatch(r -> r.role.equals(userRole) && r.isUnexpired());
}
```

This approach using `anyMatch()` will be clear to future readers of your code without any ambiguity.

Why not use the stream/filter/findFirst approach?  At minimum, it's possible based on just the info in the OP to have multiple entries in the `private Collection<Role> roles` with same UseRole and different  expiry dates.  `findFirst()` will be produce indeterminate results unless you do something to ensure ordering of the collection (Collection itself has no guarantees on order) or do the expiration check in the filter.  Even with check in filter, I argue  `anyMatch()` is less open for question on your intent.

Comment: It's a good answer but it is a kind of shortcut which has nothing to do with handling `Optional` returned by `Stream::findFirst` as stated in the question :)

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Optional::map` to retrieve value of `isUnexpired`, and `orElse` to return `false`:

```java
public boolean hasRole (UserRole userRole) {
    return roles.stream()
        .filter(r -> r.getRole().equals(userRole))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Role::isUnexpired)
        .orElse(false);
}
```

---

In case there are *multiple* identical roles with *different* expiration dates (a bit weird use case mentioned by @Ray), additional sorting by the expiry date (descending) may be needed to resolve the conflict:

```java
public boolean hasRole (UserRole userRole) {
    return roles.stream()
        .filter(r -> r.getRole().equals(userRole))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Role::getExpiry).reversed())
        .findFirst()
        .map(Role::isUnexpired)
        .orElse(false);
}
```

Comment: As theres no guarantee in the OP question of not having multiple instances of a role in the `roles` collection with different expiry dates but identical `UserRole`.  It just asks:  "I want to know if a User has a particular UserRole and it is unexpired".  Your method  would return `false` if the first match for a UserRole found in stream is expired, but theres a later one in the stream is unexpired.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would rather do it with a cleaner, chained function.

Why would a chained function be 'cleaner'? As you can see, it makes it *much* more difficult to adapt code to changing requirements, *and* enforces weird style choices on your other code in order to dance around the fact that you can't use mutable local variables and don't get control flow or checked exception transparency. I don't know what definition of 'cleaner' you're working on, but clearly it's not "code that leads to easier to modify, easier to test, easier to read, easier to fit inside code with other requirements", which seems like a much more sensible definition to me. Perhaps your definition is based in aesthetics. Well, as they say, you can't argue with taste, perhaps.

At any rate, you have two options:

### Map optional.NONE onto a sentinel that then fails the test.

You can simply use `.orElse()` here:

```java
...
.findFirst()
.orElse(dummyRoleThatIsDefinitelyExpired)
.isUnexpired();
```

### Map the optional.SOME

```java
...
.findFirst()
.map(r -> r.isUnexpired())
.orElse(false);
```

The `map` call will return either an Optional.NONE, or an Optional of `Boolean.TRUE` or an optional of Boolean.FALSE. We then `orElse` the NONE case onto FALSE and we now have a boolean to return.

I'd say the first snippet is easier to follow, but it requires having a dummy role that is definitely expired.

NB: If you care about clean functions, sticking negatives in boolean method names is not a good idea for obvious reasons. Instead of `Unexpired`, perhaps `isLive()` or `isValid()` is a better idea.